# Color de letra no cambia Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-layout, text-color

estoy desarrollando una app para mi empresa y actualmente tengo un problema que quizás sea simple de resolver pero no he podido hacerlo.
Trato de cambiar el color de la letra en el XML, en el código se hace y en la vista de diseño también, sin embargo el problema es cuando paso la app a mi teléfono ya que esta se mantiene de color blanco y no cambia a ningún otro.

Codigo actual del XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button46"
    android:layout_width="246dp"
    android:layout_height="189dp"
    android:background="@drawable/folder"
    android:text="@string/operadores"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button45" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button45"
    android:layout_width="246dp"
    android:layout_height="189dp"
    android:background="@drawable/folder"
    android:forceDarkAllowed="true"
    android:text="@string/personal_indefinido"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:textColorLink="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button46"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa *en el código se hace*? Explica qué haces para depurar tu App. Si usas el emulador o el dispositivo conectado por USB (si la App se instala de nuevo en este caso), etc.

Comment: Me refiero a que en el diseño el color cambia mas no cuando corro la app mediante el teléfono, solo se ve de color blanco el texto. La depuración la realizo mediante el teléfono conectado.

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta el código de la Activity o Fragment donde pones el texto. Dinos también a qué elemento te refieres, en el XML veo dos botones.

Answer (score 0):

> El código de tu botón debería ser similar a esto

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button46"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/operadores"
android:textColor="@android:color/colorPrimary"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button45" />
```

> Los colores, siempre deben llamarse a través de un archivo de recursos, deberías tener un xml llamado, **colors.xml**
>
> Tu archivo de colores, debe contener esto

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#172434</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#fd6f30</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#0C1826</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryEmpty">#ffcccc</color>
    </resources>
```